# Purpose of through2-map

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

Can someone please explain `through2-map` package of `Node.js?

I have read the package NPM page, but still the purpose of `through2-map` is not totally clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its all in the docs.  `through2-map` gives a more concise way to achieve what you want.

Instead of having:

```
 function (chunk, encoding, callback) { // in through2 
   this.push(chunk.slice(0, 10))
   return callback()
 }
```

you have a shorter version:

```
 function (chunk) { // in through2-map
   return chunk.slice(0, 10);
 }
```

No explicit callback calling.

Comment: thanks @kyrylkov ! i have seen the docs but my concept about it still not clear.

Comment: @kunal do you understand what `through2` does?  do you understand `transform` stream?

Comment: @kunal do you understand what `transform` stream does?

Comment: @kunal start here.  you need to grasp all the concepts well https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook

Comment: thanks @kyrylkoy ! I will go through it and will make the concept clear